# Grabbing <title> from segment path

Tags: expressionengine

I have a site, using EE 1.73, set up with various weblogs and am trying to pass the correct info to the html  tag.

I have added the following to the  tag -

```
{if segment_3}
<title>{site_name} | {exp:weblog:entries weblog=“features|reviews|tutorials|catchreports|news|species|rigs|videos” limit=“1” disable=“categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks”
}{weblog} | {title}{/exp:weblog:entries}</title>
{if:else}
<title>{site_name}</title>
{/if}
```

And this correctly give the title for the home page as - Planet Sea Fishing Digital Magazine

The actual article title is fine too with http://www.planetseafishing.com/reviews/read/the-reel-service-centre/ being rendered correctly as Planet Sea Fishing Digital Magazine | Reviews | The Reel Service Centre

My problem, as a beginner, is that I can’t figure out how to get the page title for the actual weblog to render correctly ie for http://www.planetseafishing.com/reviews/ to show as Planet Sea Fishing Digital Magazine | Reviews

I presume that it has something to do with using the fact that segment_3 is blank in this case but no matter what I try I can’t get the title to render properly.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

David

Comment: If your question doesn't get the attention you need here, consider posting it in http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using one template to serve the site index, the weblog listing and the weblog entries?  If so you could try nested your conditionals like this:

```
{if segment_3}
<title>{site_name} | {exp:weblog:entries weblog="features|reviews|tutorials|catchreports|news|species|rigs|videos" limit="1" disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
}{weblog} | {title}{/exp:weblog:entries}</title>
{if:else}
    {if segment_2}
    <title>{site_name} | {exp:weblog:entries weblog="features|reviews|tutorials|catchreports|news|species|rigs|videos" limit="1" disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}{weblog}{/exp:weblog:entries}</title>
    {if:else}
    <title>{site_name}</title>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

I don't quite understand your structure tho.  Based on your url it looks like "reviews" is a template group as well as a weblog.  Does each weblog have it's own template group?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in EE 1.x, the title for the **weblog** can be accessed via the EE variable {blog_title}, which is different than the {title} variable used to access the **entry** title.

Try this code, without any conditionals. By the inclusion of the "require entry=yes" parameter, hopefully this code will only show your expanded blog and page titles when the result of your {exp:weblog:entries} call actually returns an entry - i.e., when there's dynamic data to present via the URI. Otherwise, it shouldn't display anything.

Hopefully I'm not missing your intent!

```
<title>{site_name}{exp:weblog:entries weblog=“features|reviews|tutorials|catchreports|news|species|rigs|videos” limit=“1” disable=“categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks” require_entry="yes"
} | {blog_title} | {title}{/exp:weblog:entries}</title>
```